# How to replace horrible font in a single program?

Tags: 20.04, fonts

I'm running a very old program, closed source, no longer updated, which has a horrible font. There's no option to change font in the program; can I somehow force that program to use another font? Example:
[image]

Comment: Horrible idea: replace the font file with the font you want. This usually works if the font glyphs fit in the same boxes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The program appears to use hard-coded fonts. The program contains internal strings that reference Tcl/Tk and font lists.

If you're willing to use a beta version, [WXtoimg 2.11.2 beta](https://wxtoimgrestored.xyz/downloads/) uses a sans-serif font.

[image: 2.11.2 beta]

---

It *might* be possible to change the font via [X resources](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/X_resources), but I don't know how.

- [Is there a way to find all X resources an application uses?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12613/)
- `editres` doesn't appear to work. Stuck at: "Message sent to client asking for widget tree."

Comment: This is a very old interface, so resources are rare. But see for example [Gilles' answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/12632) to "Is there a way to find all X resources an application uses?".